# Seaborn stripplot and errorbars

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I have a pandas data frame containing categorical data that looks like this:

```
      cat     DM3_r  DM3_r_err
133   stuff  9.908949   0.442363
1347  foo  1.156828   0.130174
132   bar  0.818709   0.593341
1350  stack  0.798348   0.089866
977   over  0.724274   0.462868
1054  flow  0.546665   0.538208
1228  run  0.425070   0.571659
1009  run  0.316554   0.259385
1109  yadG  0.304657   0.401482
```

I am using seaborn's stripplot to visualize the data:

```
seaborn.stripplot(df.DM3_r, df.cat, size=7, orient="h", 
              palette="Reds_r", edgecolor="gray", ax=ax.flat[i], linewidth=.5)
```

for different groups of `"cat"` in this case. This works fine. However, I would like to add the errors `"DM3_r_err"`.

I already tried `errorbar` from `matplotlib` to add an errorbar plot on top, but I could not extract the positions of the points in the seaborn chart. Which is likely due to the fact that I am using subplots.

Is there a direct way using seaborn?

This is how the stripplot looks like (left) and on the right side is what I aim for:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be smarter ways to select the data from the `Pandas.DataFrame`, but something like this works:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import seaborn
import numpy as np

pl.close('all')

data = [['hsdM', 3.908949, 1.442363],
        ['lolD', 1.156828, 0.456434],
        ['lolD', 3.156828, 0.230174],
        ['acrB', 0.546665, 0.538208],
        ['msbA', 0.425070, 0.571659],
        ['msbA', 2.425070, 1.571659],
        ['emrA', 0.316554, 1.259385],
        ['yadG', 0.304657, 0.401482]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['gene','DM3_r','DM3_r_err'])

pl.figure()
ax = pl.subplot(111)

# Everywhere below you would have to replace `ax` with your `ax.flat[i]`
sp = seaborn.stripplot(df.DM3_r, df.gene, size=7, orient="h", 
                     palette="Reds_r", edgecolor="gray", ax=ax, linewidth=.5)

for y,ylabel in zip(ax.get_yticks(), ax.get_yticklabels()):
    f = df['gene'] == ylabel.get_text() 
    ax.errorbar(df.DM3_r[f].values, np.ones_like(df.DM3_r[f].values)*y, xerr=df.DM3_r_err[f].values, ls='none')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Bart. I actually figured the same using the tick location for the y axis.